# Limit a Docker container's disk IO - AWS EBS/EC2 Instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, web-services, amazon-ec2, io

When I run a new install of WordPress or a simple build command for some of my web apps in Jenkins the server grinds to a halt. In Netdata it appears the culprit is high "iowait".

I know that I can increase the IOPS on the EBS volume but I'd rather just wait a longer time for the process to finish. Is there a way to limit IOPS on a docker container (in this case; my Jenkins container)?

Answer (score 1):

Try `--device-read-iops` and `--device-write-iops` option of docker run command.

The command should be something like this

```
docker run -itd --device-read-iops /dev/sda:100 --device-write-iops /dev/sda:100 image-name
```

*NOTE: /dev/sda is the device name and 100 is number of iops per second*

You can also limit io in terms of bytes using 
--device-read-bps and --device-write-bps option.

Check this documentation for more info.
https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/

Comment: Thank you, is there a way to get the correct device name? (using an EC2 instance with an EBS volume mounted)

Comment: Run `df -h` and grep for ebs mount point, the device name will be something like /dev/somedevicename.